# Привязка к родителю

Tags: c#, .net, binding

Имеется шаблон данных. В нём производится привязка данных из некоторого класса, содержащего свойства Name, Symbol, Value, Min, Max и Dimension. Привязка первых трёх свойств осуществляется успешно. Проблемы начинаются при использовании валидации и конвертера, как показано в коде. Как я полагаю, парсер Xaml ищет свойства Min, Max и Dimension среди свойств Value, а оно является строкой. Следовательно, в Min, Max и Dimension падает Null. Пытался решить эту проблему, поигравшись с RelativeSource, но безрезультатно. Есть идеи?

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Width="430" Height="30" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBlock Width="60" Height="30" Text="{Binding Symbol, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBox Width="100" Height="30">
                <Binding Path="Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <calc:VarValidation>
                            <calc:VarValidation.Params>
                                <calc:ValidationParams Min="{Binding Min}" Max="{Binding Max}" />
                            </calc:VarValidation.Params>
                        </calc:VarValidation>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <Binding.Converter>
                        <measuring:TemperatureConvert >
                            <measuring:TemperatureConvert.myParameter>
                                <Binding Path="Dimension" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}" diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" />
                            </measuring:TemperatureConvert.myParameter>

                        </measuring:TemperatureConvert>
                    </Binding.Converter>

                </Binding>
            </TextBox>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

Как я понял, автор статьи с помощью такой конструкции

```
<Window.Resources>
    <FrameworkElement x:Key="DataContextBridge" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Mode="OneWayToSource" Path="DataContext" Source="{StaticResource DataContextBridge}" />
</Window.DataContext>
```

сбрасывает корневой элемент контекста данных в контекст данных некоторого FrameworkElement, после чего данные для целевого элемента берёт из созданного FrameworkElement'a. Но для назначения контекста данных он использует код:

```
this.DataContext = nums;
```

Можно ли сделать то же самое с помощью Xaml-разметки? Это необходимо из-за того, что в моём случае используется шаблон данных, элементы которого повторяются на форме многократно, следовательно, они не имеют имени, по которому можно обратиться к целевому элементу. А без явного задания контекста данных он равен null.

```
<TextBox.Resources>
    <FrameworkElement x:Key="DataContextBridge" />
</TextBox.Resources>
<TextBox.DataContext> <!-- Здесь null. Как исправить? -->
    <Binding Mode="OneWayToSource" Path="DataContext" Source="{StaticResource DataContextBridge}" />
</TextBox.DataContext>
```

Comment: А так вы пробовали:

    <TextBox Width="100" Height="30">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Value"
                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                ...

?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Value работает без проблем, и триггер обновления установлен на PropertyChanged, просто я его опустил для краткости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственное верное решение нашёл [здесь](http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-add-binding-to-property-on.html). Заработало почти сразу. Только немного изменил код разметки.

```
<Window.Resources>  
    <my:DataResource x:Key="max" BindingTarget="{Binding Max}"/>  
    <my:DataResource x:Key="min" BindingTarget="{Binding Min}"/>  
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox>  
    <TextBox.Text>  
        <Binding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Path="Value">  
            <Binding.ValidationRules>  
                <my:IntValidationRule   
                    ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"   
                    Min="{Binding Source={StaticResource min}, Path=BindingTarget}"
                    Max="{Binding Source={StaticResource max}, Path=BindingTarget}">  
                </my:IntValidationRule>  
            </Binding.ValidationRules>  
        </Binding>  
    </TextBox.Text>  
</TextBox>
```

Comment: @Alouette: Угу. Это решение было в комментариях к статье по моей ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

А почему просто не перенести проверку в класс данных? Например так:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _dimension;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Dimension
    {
        get { return _dimension; }
        set
        {
            if(value>Max||value<Min)
            throw new ArgumentException("Поле Dimention должно быть больше минимума но меньше максимума");
           _dimension = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда и разметка поменьше будет:

```
<TextBox Width="100" Height="30" Text="{Binding Dimension, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Например, потому, что это не дело бизнес логики, знать о наличии UI и выставлять свойства специально для отображения.

Comment: Ну, не обязательно вносить такие изменения в модель данных. Можно сделать модель представления, как обертку модели, и выставить правила валидации там. И модель не страдает, и в разметке лишнего нет, и кучу правил валидации писать не надо. А там и до MVVM не далеко.

Comment: @Pleshkov Ivan: Я лично противник того, чтобы VM знала о View (и соответственно выставляла для него правила валидации), хотя, конечно, вопрос дискутируемый. Я обычно располагаю бизнес-логику на уровне VM, а весь код, отвечающий за отображение, уношу во View. Иначе за отображение ответственны два уровня логики — не чересчур ли много чести?

Comment: @Pleshkov Ivan Ваше решение, казалось бы, лежит на поверхности. Но @VladD правильно сказал: не нужно делать логику и отображение совместно. Кроме того, при генерировании необработанного исключения происходит отображение диалогового окна с текстом ошибки, а валидация позволяет избежать этого, при этом целевое поле ввода подсвечивается красным. Хотя можно попробовать сделать по-вашему конвертер.

Comment: @Alouette, насчет исключений - согласен. Мне не очень нравится подход с исключениями. Я стараюсь делать реализацию IDataError или INotifyDataError. И исключений нет, и конвертеры и валидаторы не нужны. Насчет логики: книги и статьи, которые читал, указывают на то, что ViewModel - это логика презентационного уровня, и укладывать в неё логику модели (бизнес-логику) действительно неуместно. Но в очень простых проектах я считаю возможным совмещать бизнес-логику с презентационной. В сложных - переношу бизнес-логику в модель. Это тема многих холиваров и личных или корпоративных предпочтений.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, вы не можете установить привязку к параметру объекта таким образом. Для начала, вам пришлось сделать `TemperatureConvert` `DependencyObject`'ом, правильно? Это уже не очень хорошо, конвертер не является таковым. И даже если вы заставили это скомпилироваться, работать всё равно не будет, так как обновление свойств через Binding проходит только для элементов визуального дерева, а ни `TemperatureConvert`, ни тем более его параметр таковым не являются. Наверняка вы получаете предупреждения наподобие

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element ...

в окне Output.

Попробуйте сделать `TemperatureConvert` `IMultiValueConverter`'ом и сделать к нему `MultiBinding`.

---

Тем не менее, может быть это поможет: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18678/Attaching-a-Virtual-Branch-to-the-Logical-Tree-in

Comment: См. Update.